How do i get this filter class view to work since first two views are working?
Just started learning django. I can't get the filtering for this to work:
views.py:
class BlogPostList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        title = request.query_params.get("title", "")
        
        if title:
            blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(title_icontains=title)
        else:
            blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
        
        serializer = BlogPostSerializer(blog_posts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path("blogposts/", views.BlogPostListCreate.as_view(), name="Blogpost-view-create"),
    path("blogposts/<int:pk>/", views.BlogPostRetrieveUpdateDestroy.as_view(), name="update"),
    path("blogposts/", views.BlogPostList.as_view(), name="Filter"),

]

the first two views work.
models.py:
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


here's the full views.py code:
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import BlogPost
from .serializers import BlogPostSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView

# Create your views here.


class BlogPostListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        BlogPost.objects.all().delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)



class BlogPostRetrieveUpdateDestroy(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
    lookup_field = "pk"

class BlogPostList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        title = request.query_params.get("title", "")
        
        if title:
            blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(title_icontains=title)
        else:
            blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
        
        serializer = BlogPostSerializer(blog_posts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    


You need double underscores before using field lookups __icontains

still doesnt work

Typo: title_icontains should be title__icontains

The first (Blockpost-view-create) and third (Filter) paths in your url configuration are identical.
Since django uses the first matching path, it will never reach the path named Filter.

So what would be the correct paths?

This is up to you. The only thing you should watch out for, paths should be unique.

First, make sure all your url paths are unique.
Under the BlogPostList view, you don't filter using icontains with single underscore, instead of the below query:
blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(title_icontains=title)

The correct one is:
blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(title__icontains=title)


Add this to the url
path("blogposts/search/", views.BlogPostList.as_view(), name="blogpost-search"),
